# Magento: Rewriting URLs dynamically depending on conditions?

Tags: magento, url-rewriting, controller

I have this problem:

I have a default route that looks like this: .../myapp/index.php/**config**/configuration/test/product_id/51

As you see, this leads to the ConfigurationController and in there to the testAction function. Thats fine and it should stay this way. What I want to change though is the "config part" of the URL.

So instead of

http://somedomain.de/myapp/index.php/**config**/configuration/test/product_id/51

I want

http://somedomain.de/myapp/index.php/**furniture**/configuration/test/product_id/51

to lead to the same location (ConfigurationController and in there to the testAction function). The part that is changed, is not static, its the attribute set name of the product. So instead of furniture it can be computer or something else. I can already get this from the product, So all I need is the rewrite stuff.

Ideas how to do that? THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

In the module's `config.xml` you can change the `frontend`/`routers`/`your_router`/`args`/`frontName` which will allow you to use a different name (like furniture). If its an adminhtml controller, you have to use an `adminhtml` router but the rest is the same.

Comment: Yeah, I know I can change it there, but it has to be dynamic, you know? Having furniture there, would not work with anything else but furniture. I have to make it work with more than just one frontName.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a router, just like Magento does for CMS pages (explained in the second part of this article : http://alanstorm.com/magento_dispatch_admin_cms_default_routers)

Comment: Thanks, where does the 2nd part start?

Comment: It starts with `The CMS Router Object`.  
And in the meantime, you can get inspiration from the `Mage_Cms` core  module and its `Mage_Cms_Controller_Router` class

Comment: Which URL will be shown after the router did its work? The one containing "config"?

Comment: It will depend on how you code your own router, but yes, if that's the action you want to redirect to, it will be possible